# How to get hovered vertex world space position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, mouseevent, vertex

I'm working on an editor tool and I have a problem.

If in the SceneView I hover with a mouse over a mesh vertex, how can I get its position in world space?

Answer (score 0):

In your Editor Script, you need to raycast from current mouse position, transform this via `HandleUtility` and handle if the `hitInfo.collider` contains the requested object.

Note: I didn't test if this works if you don't have a collider attached

This also works only after SceneView has the focus (you clicked on it)

```
void OnSceneGUI()
{
    Transform objectPreview;  //the transform to move
    Transform objectTouched = null; //the reference of the last object hit
    
    Ray worldRay = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay(Event.current.mousePosition);
    
    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    
    if (Physics.Raycast(worldRay, out hitInfo, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject != null)
        {
            objectTouched = hitInfo.collider.gameObject;
            var yourPosition = objectTouched.transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'll give this a go!